# Where is the source code for the .NET's Monitor class?

Tags: .net, .net-core

I'm curious about how some low-level .NET classes are implemented. I took the Monitor class as an example. However, I can't seem to find it on GitHub. The closest I got to was [Monitor.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/32f0f9721afb584b4a14d69135bea7ddc129f755/src/mscorlib/src/System/Threading/Monitor.cs) in [coreclr](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr). However, the code in this file just references `extern` methods with `[MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]` for anything substantial.

This is where I got stuck. Where can I find the implementation of those internal methods?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Those are implemented as [FCalls](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/botr/mscorlib.md) in the CLR.

[Here](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/a9c90ffd84e987a1793a1ed5c5ad7d89b27d493a/src/vm/ecalllist.h#L1824-L1833)'s the list of `Monitor`-related internal calls:

```
FCFuncStart(gMonitorFuncs)
    FCFuncElement("Enter", JIT_MonEnter)
    FCFuncElement("ReliableEnter", JIT_MonReliableEnter)
    FCFuncElement("ReliableEnterTimeout", JIT_MonTryEnter)
    FCFuncElement("Exit", JIT_MonExit)
    FCFuncElement("ObjWait", ObjectNative::WaitTimeout)
    FCFuncElement("ObjPulse", ObjectNative::Pulse)
    FCFuncElement("ObjPulseAll", ObjectNative::PulseAll)
    FCFuncElement("IsEnteredNative", ObjectNative::IsLockHeld)
FCFuncEnd()
```

So if you want to look for the definition of the `Enter` method for instance, you'll have to look for `JIT_MonEnter` (in this case, it's a JIT helper [here](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/3891c5f681eccd262f1ccca4bfa34a582573ce1d/src/vm/jithelpers.cpp#L4638-L4679))

Comment: Updated (dotnet/runtime repo) links for [ecalllist.h](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/8902a955be55b5076527be87288a6014c45af8d9/src/coreclr/vm/ecalllist.h#L538) and [Start of JIT_MonEnter_Portable implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/c81e7a216a3f3c65ae2803381815861d846a7a74/src/coreclr/vm/jithelpers.cpp#L3597-L3607)

Implementation is tightly connected with [syncblock and awarelock](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/4fc3eb443a3f8f8917038fbdba9049caf288020c/src/coreclr/vm/syncblk.h#L149-L157).

Answer (score 0):

If somebody is interested in the logic, the closest thing I found is [this](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/e3547f1d3ac768a14a0598abf7868641ecf0c9d7/src/coreclr/vm/syncblk.inl#L588) from the coreclr repo.
Code:

```
FORCEINLINE AwareLock::EnterHelperResult ObjHeader::EnterObjMonitorHelper(Thread* pCurThread)
{
    CONTRACTL{
        NOTHROW;
        GC_NOTRIGGER;
        MODE_COOPERATIVE;
    } CONTRACTL_END;

    LONG oldValue = m_SyncBlockValue.LoadWithoutBarrier();

    if ((oldValue & (BIT_SBLK_IS_HASH_OR_SYNCBLKINDEX +
                     BIT_SBLK_SPIN_LOCK +
                     SBLK_MASK_LOCK_THREADID +
                     SBLK_MASK_LOCK_RECLEVEL)) == 0)
    {
        DWORD tid = pCurThread->GetThreadId();
        if (tid > SBLK_MASK_LOCK_THREADID)
        {
            return AwareLock::EnterHelperResult_UseSlowPath;
        }

        LONG newValue = oldValue | tid;
#if defined(TARGET_WINDOWS) && defined(TARGET_ARM64)
        if (FastInterlockedCompareExchangeAcquire((LONG*)&m_SyncBlockValue, newValue, oldValue) == oldValue)
#else   
        if (InterlockedCompareExchangeAcquire((LONG*)&m_SyncBlockValue, newValue, oldValue) == oldValue)
#endif
        {
            return AwareLock::EnterHelperResult_Entered;
        }

        return AwareLock::EnterHelperResult_Contention;
    }

    if (oldValue & BIT_SBLK_IS_HASH_OR_SYNCBLKINDEX)
    {
        // If we have a hash code already, we need to create a sync block
        if (oldValue & BIT_SBLK_IS_HASHCODE)
        {
            return AwareLock::EnterHelperResult_UseSlowPath;
        }

        SyncBlock *syncBlock = g_pSyncTable[oldValue & MASK_SYNCBLOCKINDEX].m_SyncBlock;
        _ASSERTE(syncBlock != NULL);
        if (syncBlock->m_Monitor.TryEnterHelper(pCurThread))
        {
            return AwareLock::EnterHelperResult_Entered;
        }

        return AwareLock::EnterHelperResult_Contention;
    }

    // The header is transitioning - use the slow path
    if (oldValue & BIT_SBLK_SPIN_LOCK)
    {
        return AwareLock::EnterHelperResult_UseSlowPath;
    }

    // Here we know we have the "thin lock" layout, but the lock is not free.
    // It could still be the recursion case - compare the thread id to check
    if (pCurThread->GetThreadId() != (DWORD)(oldValue & SBLK_MASK_LOCK_THREADID))
    {
        return AwareLock::EnterHelperResult_Contention;
    }

    // Ok, the thread id matches, it's the recursion case.
    // Bump up the recursion level and check for overflow
    LONG newValue = oldValue + SBLK_LOCK_RECLEVEL_INC;

    if ((newValue & SBLK_MASK_LOCK_RECLEVEL) == 0)
    {
        return AwareLock::EnterHelperResult_UseSlowPath;
    }

#if defined(TARGET_WINDOWS) && defined(TARGET_ARM64)
    if (FastInterlockedCompareExchangeAcquire((LONG*)&m_SyncBlockValue, newValue, oldValue) == oldValue)
#else
    if (InterlockedCompareExchangeAcquire((LONG*)&m_SyncBlockValue, newValue, oldValue) == oldValue)
#endif
    {
        return AwareLock::EnterHelperResult_Entered;
    }

    // Use the slow path instead of spinning. The compare-exchange above would not fail often, and it's not worth forcing the
    // spin loop that typically follows the call to this function to check the recursive case, so just bail to the slow path.
    return AwareLock::EnterHelperResult_UseSlowPath;
}
```